# Extra columns created in Azure Table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am inserting data in table storage by mapping one object to entity object. But some how mapping object columns been created as entity columns even passing entity object for creating records.
Both entity object and mapping object columns are getting created in table storage.

Below line is used for creating record.
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(EntityObject);

Instead of entity object columns created in table storage some extra columns are getting created from custom object where I am mapping to entity object.

Comment: Cant understand the question or the problem - please give more info

Comment: I am mapping custom object to my entity object and trying to create record but  some extra columns getting with Entity object columns. If I have 5 columns in entity object 10 columns are getting created, other five are getting created from my custom object.

Comment: Can you add additional code that shows what you are doing? Is your entity object derived from your custom object?

Comment: **Please add the following details to your post**: 1) Complete code (the code you mentioned is just not sufficient to identify the problem) 2) Code for your `EntityObject` 3) Describe what you columns you were expecting and what you got in reality. Without these details it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: I am just Assigning EntityObj.ID = customObj.ID. Then TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(EntityObject);